# How to fix syntax error when renaming the files in a specific folder in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
'This method renames all the filenames in a folder
Sub RenameAllFilenamesInAFolder()
    Dim intRowCount As Integer
    Dim intCtr As Integer
    Dim strFileNameExisting As String
    Dim strFileNameNew As String
    Dim strFolder As String
     
    'Set the folder path
    strFolder = "C:\Users\rchandramohan\"
     
    With Sheet1
        'Find the total rows count in the sheet
        'This will be the last non-blank cell in column A...
        intRowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         
        'Loop through from the 2nd row (1st row is Heading)
        'till the total rows in the sheet
        For intCtr = 2 To intRowCount
            'Get the existing filename from the cell
            strFileNameExisting = .Range("A" & intCtr)
    
            'Get the new filename from the cell
            strFileNameNew = .Range("B" & intCtr)
             
            'Rename the file
          ** Name strFolder & strFileNameExisting As strFolder & strFileNameNew **
        Next intCtr
    End With
     
    'Display an appropriate message, once complete
    MsgBox "All files renamed successfully!", _
                        vbInformation, "All files renamed"
End Sub
```

I am using the above code for renaming the files in a folder, I am getting the syntax error in the line where I have marked ** before and after the particular line,

```
Name strFolder & strFileNameExisting As strFolder & strFileNameNew
```

[image]

Comment: Put a break point on the line, run the function,and and check the values of strFolder, strFileNameExisting, strFolder, & strFileNameNew.

Comment: What kind of syntax error do you get? For me the code compiles without any sytnax error. Do you have any library loaded which overrides `Name`?

Comment: I am getting the error window saying File not found with the Debug and other buttons. When I click on 'Debug' button, it shows that particular line with a yellow colour. I dont have any libraries which overrides

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?  Is `strFileNameNew` a valid Windows file name?

Comment: It is saying, 'File not found' and yes, strFileNameNew is a valid filename

Answer (score 0):

The code runs fine for me in Windows. If you're using Mac, this might be the reason why it produces that error.

Comment: I am also using windows.

Comment: I need a little clarification. Is the above code renames all its subfolders too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should run fine, however, I suggest you add variable definitions at the beginning.
Here is the code with some modifications and the working excel sheet link

```
Sub RenameAllFilenamesInAFolder()
Dim intRowCount As Integer
Dim intCtr As Integer
Dim strFileNameExisting As String
Dim strFileNameNew As String
Dim strFolder As String

strFolder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
With Sheet1
    intRowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For intCtr = 2 To intRowCount
        If Not .Range("C" & intCtr) Then
            strFileNameExisting = .Range("A" & intCtr)
            strFileNameNew = .Range("B" & intCtr)
            Name strFolder & strFileNameExisting As strFolder & strFileNameNew
            .Range("C" & intCtr) = True
        End If
    Next intCtr
End With
MsgBox "All files renamed successfully!", _
       vbInformation, "All files renamed" 
End Sub
```

[Working Excel File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V_8Y6rvCS3bZmSplIDHza8jWkrPqOFNj/view?usp=sharing)